# Reset count function in counter app not setting count to 0

Tags: reactjs

I am facing a problem in resetting the count to 0 in my counter app. It's not resetting the count to 0 for any counter and I have tried `console.log` each counter.count but it's showing `undefined`.

`App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Counter from "./components/Counter";

export class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counters: []
  };

  addCounter = () => {
    this.setState({
      counters: [...this.state.counters, Counter]
    });
  };

  reset = () => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.map(counter => {
      counter.count = 0;
      return counter;
    });
    // console.log(counters.count);
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
        <button onClick={this.addCounter}>Add Counter</button>
        {this.state.counters.map((Counter, index) => (
          <Counter key={index} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`Counter.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class Counter extends Component {
    state={
        count:0,
      }

      increment=()=>{
        this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
      }

      decrement=()=>{
        this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <span><button onClick={this.increment}>+</button></span>

          <span>{this.state.count}</span>
          <span><button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button></span>
          </div>


        )
      }
}

export default Counter
```

Reset counter should reset the count to 0 for all the counters.

Comment: You cannot reset counters in app because app haas an array of Counter classes and no data. Try to make this.state.counters be the data (`{counter:0}`) and pass the increment and decrement function to the Counter class

Comment: Example of what you can do [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-react-webpack-oeqhd)

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
this.setState({
      counters: [...this.state.counters, Counter]
});
```

you saved a `React Class` into `counters`. So when you map to reset to 0, you need `New Class` to get `state.count` like this:

```
reset = () => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.map(counter => {
      (new counter()).state.count = 0;
      return counter;
    });

    for (let counter of counters) {
      console.log((new counter()).state);
    }
    this.setState({ counters });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's time to [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Move all your `increment` and `decrement` and `reset` functions to parent, `App`.

Also, add a separate array `count` state to monitor current count for each counter.

```
// App
export class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counters: [],
    count: [] // additional state to store count for each counter
  };

  addCounter = () => {
    this.setState({
      counters: [...this.state.counters, Counter],
      count: [...this.state.count, 0]
    });
  };

  reset = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count.map(c => 0)
    });
  };

  // lifted up from Counter
  increment = index => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count.map((c, i) => (i === index ? c + 1 : c))
    });
  };

  // lifted up from Counter
  decrement = index => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count.map((c, i) => (i === index ? c - 1 : c))
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.addCounter}>Add Counter</button>
        <button onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
        {this.state.counters.map((Counter, index) => (
          <Counter
            key={index}
            increment={() => this.increment(index)}
            decrement={() => this.decrement(index)}
            count={this.state.count[index]}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
// Counter
export class Counter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>
          <button onClick={this.props.increment}>+</button>
        </span>
        <span>{this.props.count}</span>
        <span>
          <button onClick={this.props.decrement}>-</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/falling-darkness-s83lk)